# Search for duplicate before adding to list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to search for duplicates in a list before adding there any information. Could you please take a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Another question is how could I iterate `arrayList` using `Object.entries(arrayList)`-loop and get the same result as I got w/o using it? When I tried to use `Object.entries` I was only able to see `0 [object Object]`, `1 [object Object]` instead of names and genders.

```js
let arrayList = [{
    "name": "Brandon",
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "name": "Charlotte",
    "gender": "F"
  },
];

let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function() {
  let showHere = document.getElementById("showHere");

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {

    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let text = `${arrayList[i].name} ${arrayList[i].gender}`;
    let insert = document.createTextNode(text);
    if (arrayList[i].name.indexOf(li) != -1) {
      alert(`${arrayList[i].name} already in list`);
    } else {
      li.appendChild(insert);
      showHere.appendChild(li);
    }
    console.log(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Show list</button>
<ul id="showHere"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm not 100% sure what you intended but, you may consider instead of checking for duplicates, clearing out the array before re-rendering it with new values. I modified your snippet so you can see what I'm talking about.

If you have any questions feel free to make a comment!

[Edit] I added a little snippet to check if a name gender combo already exists before adding it to the list.

```js
let arrayList = [{
    "name": "Brandon",
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "name": "Charlotte",
    "gender": "F"
  },
];

let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const addBtn = document.getElementById('add');

addBtn.onclick = function() {
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  const gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
  
  // check if value already exists

  if(!arrayList.find(obj => JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify({name, gender}))){
    arrayList.push({
    name,
    gender
   });
  } else {
    console.log('name gender combo already exists');
  }
  

}

btn.onclick = function() {
  let showHere = document.getElementById("showHere");
  showHere.innerHTML  = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {

    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let text = `${arrayList[i].name} ${arrayList[i].gender}`;
    let insert = document.createTextNode(text);
    if (arrayList[i].name.indexOf(li) != -1) {
      alert(`${arrayList[i].name} already in list`);
    } else {
      li.appendChild(insert);
      showHere.appendChild(li);
    }
    console.log(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" ></input>
<input type="text" id="gender" ></input>
<button type="button" id="add">Add to list</button>

<button type="button" id="btn">Show list</button>
<ul id="showHere"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but this is not what I'm actually looking for. This is my fault that I didn't fully explain that situation. Here are the few things I'm not able to do: 1) I can't modify the structure of HTML (only button and ul-tag), 2) I can't use jQuery. How should the script work: when I push the button for the first time `arrayList` should appear into the list and when I push it a second time, script should check if the data is already in `li`-tag.